# Extract URL of that profile after searching a name(from the first result) in LinkedIn in python

Tags: python, selenium

I need to get the URL of the first profile which I get after searching the name in the search bar.

What I have done till now -

Login into LinkedIn and search a name and then press enter. Now I need to just get the URL of that profile.

I have tried searching and exploring but I didn't get any way to extract link in this way.

I am at this stage
[image] from here I just need to get the URL from the profile which came after search.

Here is my code below -

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'chrome_driver_folder_path\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("linkedin_sign_in_page_url")
username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='session_key']")))
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='session_password']")))
username.clear()
username.send_keys("your_email_here")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("your_password_here")
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()
search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[placeholder='Search']")))
search.clear()
search.send_keys("tony stark")
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

my output should be - https://www.linkedin.com/in/tony-stark-ironman/

Comment: You are accepting answer on `beautifulsoup` also right? Otherwise you may remove [tag:beautifulsoup] tag from your question.

Comment: ok, will remove it and thanks for editing my qstn, now it looks way better than the previous one.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML of the _`the URL of that profile`_ and your code trials.

Comment: Done, and code trials I have already pasted what I have done till now, after that I got stuck please help I am unable to proceed beyond that

Comment: @undetected Selenium I have made the changes as you suggested, please help if u can, I request you please